# OpenVPN : Unrecognized option or missing parameter(s) in client.ovpn:15: block-outside-dns

Tags: ssh, vpn, openvpn, client-server

None of the methods on the net worked for me so I decided to ask. When I try to

```
sudo openvpn --config client.ovpn
```

I get the result of

> Wed Aug  2 22:53:18 2017 Unrecognized option or missing parameter(s) in client.ovpn:15: block-outside-dns (2.3.10)
>
> Wed Aug  2 22:53:18 2017 OpenVPN 2.3.10 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] built on Jun 22 2017
>   Wed Aug  2 22:53:18 2017 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016, LZO 2.08
>
> Wed Aug  2 22:53:18 2017 Cannot load inline certificate file: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line: error:140AD009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file:PEM lib
>
> Wed Aug  2 22:53:18 2017 Exiting due to fatal error

I followed this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-ubuntu-16-04#step-13-test-your-vpn-connection however, it didnot worked for me it give the tls connection error missing handshake so I tried the first comment on that page which people said it works flawlessly. Well I got this error.

My client.ovpn

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
remote 146.*.*. 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
auth SHA512
cipher AES-256-CBC
comp-lzo
setenv opt block-outside-dns
key-direction 1
verb 3
<ca>
</ca>
<cert>
</cert>
<key>
</key>
<tls-auth>
```

And there is a static key

Comment: please add complete configuration

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Wed Aug 2 22:53:18 2017 Cannot load inline certificate file:
>   error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:
>   error:140AD009:SSL

It can't find the cert files or they are not valid.
Are they in the same folder as your openvpn config file? Paths are correct? Certs are valid?

Comment: When I created the client2.ovpn it does not give me any cert files ? should I take them from the server as well ? or should I create the cert files on the client computer ?

Comment: You have to create the cert files. I've read the howto you linked and there you will find all the steps